# JavaScript simple error with moving an image by its Id

Tags: javascript

In the following code I am creating a new image with the id "devildead", and after I am trying to move this image using its id, I have this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of null ).

What should I change to make it work?

```
o = document.createElement('img');
o.src = "img/birddead.png";
box.appendChild(o);
o.setAttribute("id", "devildead");
o.style.left = leftbird;
o.style.top = topbird;

// Function for moving the dead bird
var delay = 1;
var top = document.getElementById("devildead");

//Here I got the error
var currentTop = parseInt(getComputedStyle(devildead).top, 10);

// Start
setTimeout(move, delay);
function move(){
    if (currentTop <= 480) {
      currentTop += 2;
      top.style.top = currentTop + "px";
      setTimeout(move, delay);
    }
}
```

Comment: `topbird` from `o.style.top=topbird;` is not defined

Comment: devildead is not defined

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is the line causing the error

```
var currentTop = parseInt(getComputedStyle(devildead).top, 10);   
                                     //               ^^ here
```

as you don't have a `devildead` variable, for some reason you named the variable with the element `top`

```
var currentTop = parseInt(getComputedStyle(top).top, 10);
```

or even better, don't place the element in a variable called `top`, as it causes confusion

```
var devildead = document.getElementById("devildead");

var currentTop = parseInt(getComputedStyle(devildead).top, 10);
```